# K-way merge sort divided on multiple hosts

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, distributed-computing

I have ~8000 files, with ~6TB data on disk. Each file contains a list of key value pairs, and I wish to consolidate those values into a single list of sorted key-value pairs (e.g. so if key A occurs in two files, the consolidated file contains the key A once and that key contains all values from the two files).

I have implemented this [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) for a single core on a single host in Python [[gist](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/30251966f56e243a4f04740840ed2f3d) -- see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614732/divide-key-value-pairs-into-equal-lists-without-access-to-key-value-counts) for a nice intuitive overview of the procedure]. I now wish to distribute the work over multiple hosts that do not have shared memory but can have shared network access.

The key space that I need to sort is absolutely enormous, roughly 26^24, but the vast majority of keys are not present in the data (so it doesn't make sense to give each worker a set of keys with which to concern themselves).

Do others have any ideas how one could go about implementing a distributed k-way merge algorithm? This strikes me as entirely non-trivial, but there may be low hanging fruit that I'm not seeing. Any pointers others can offer would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Notes**

The compute setup is parameterizable. I'm working on two compute clusters, each will allow me to use ~10-1000 nodes concurrently, each with 12-24 cores and ~120GB RAM. The machines come online at some indeterminant time after they're requested. Network communication happens over TCP. Disks are SSD with an AFS filesystem and storage is abundant.

Additionally, I'm using a simple Python package [big-read](https://github.com/duhaime/big-read) to read only `n` lines from each of the 8,000 files into RAM at any given time, so RAM management for an "external sort" is already tractable...

Highly related: K-way merge with [stxxl](https://stxxl.org/tags/1.4.1/design_algo_sorting.html).

Comment: It would be fair to describe the infrastructure - CPU / cores, DRAM, type of ( parallel FileSystem used ) + free capacities of the storage space, interconnect unused transport capacities + an expected processing time, that you aim at -- that's fair, isn't it?

Comment: I am wondering about having each worker do a k-way merge on two files -- call those outputs 2nd order outputs. Then have subsequent workers perform k-way merges on those 2nd order outputs to produce 3rd order outputs. Continue merging in this way until we reach the final order output. This will allow the work to be distributed over many hosts.

Comment: ( Clusters are something different than any ad-hoc instantiated ***quasi*-infrastructure** that goes-up *"on-demand"* at an unknown cost-of-shared real-resources ( ref. steal-time realistically stolen from your "provisioned", but only virtualised-infrastructure (v)Nodes ), undetermined node-to-node latency and other commercially hidden *cloud-o-mania* traps ) Information about SSD storage is useless in all cases, when those 8k+ ~6TB data is somewhere "else" ( off-loaded, in a just to get collected state ) **Still missing your projects expected processing time - as a target.**

Comment: This is quite important factor, Douglas, do make some Project Management Feasibility Plan, before asking people to sponsor your work towards or against ( a still, yet undefined ) target. Given CERN published experience with ageing ( read low, since 1983 in contemporary HPC contexts ) AFS performance, limited inner protocol capabilities, the more once your job is never re-using any cache-effects ( fetched files are never reused ) + the net transport throughput will get well under < 60 MB/s per volume, the AFS makes **just an initial fetch ~ 1.5 days** ( and concurrency is not AFS's friend here)

Comment: Thx to 've stated as the known, indivisible part of the Problem formulation. Your perspective is clear, yet, HPC-infrastructure ( still not sufficiently defined here ) has some supervision team, which postulates usage-policies ( and **can terminate one's processing job** ( a worklow + CPU-/ RAM-/ IO-/ interconnect-quotas ) qiven a poor capacity / performance planning was done and the granted capacities were consumed. Have seen very smart people remain very unhappy, given their 2+ years of research has been killed on one of the Global Top-10 HPC-infrastructure, right due to bad planning.

Comment: **TARGET DEFINED : *"looking to cut this time by as much as possible"*** This is a common task for HPC domain. A smart processing strategy helped going **from days to a small tens of minutes**, if the strategy could have been designed tailor-made to the infrastructure as-is. Guess you may straight forget to install MapReduce to run accross university Andrew File System ( consult your univ. HPC-team to 1st get theirs Terms & Conditions, best geting all details on what are your real limits of resources available ( under their approval ))+ Python is not a tool they will like to see on HPC-cluster

Comment: Why are folks voting to close this question? This strikes me as perfectly in keeping with SO's policy of acceptable questions -- this one addresses an algorithmic task.

Comment: Unless the HPC-job gets administratively approved to go beyond there published limits, **you either optimise the solution-strategy** to meet the policy, **or** your submitted-HPC-job will get killed after published wall-time or will starve on low RAM & get killed ( all Cluster Administration Team Policies form a WALL that CAN&WILL break all your efforts, if run against a rule, in nanosecond. So rather be investigative, best get the whole processing consulted & approved by the HPC Team well before you decide about a computing-strategy. Not doing so will put you runnig blind against such wall(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A distributed sort/merge is very similar to a sort/merge on a single host. The basic idea is to split the files among the separate hosts. Have each host sort its individual files and then begin the merge operation that I described in [Divide key value pairs into equal lists without access to key value counts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50614732/56778). So each host has a priority queue containing the next item from each of the files that it sorted.

One of the hosts maintains a priority queue that contains the next item from each of the other hosts. It selects the first one from that queue, outputs it, and polls the host it came from for the next item, which it inserts into the priority queue and continues.

It's a priority queue of priority queues, distributed among multiple hosts. Graphically, it looks something like this:

```
   Host1            Host2             Host3            Host4
------------------------------------------------------------------
F1 F2 F3 F4      F5 F6 F7 F8      F9 F10 F11 F12   F13 F14 F15 F16
 \  |  |  /      \  |  |  /       \   |   |  /      \   |   |  /
 ----------      ----------       ------------      ------------
    PQ1             PQ2               PQ3               PQ4
     \               \                /                 /
      \               \              /                 /
       \               \            /                 /
        \               \          /                 /
          ---------------\        /------------------
                          \      /
                           \    /
                            \  /
                             --
                          Master PQ
                       on primary host
```

Now, it's highly inefficient to be requesting a single item at a time from the individual hosts. The primary host could request, say, 1,000 items from each host and hold them in individual buffers. Whenever a host's buffer runs out, the primary host requests another buffer full from the host. That will reduce the amount of network traffic.

This also reduces I/O on the individual hosts: you never have to write the combined files to disk. You sort the individual files and write them to disk as described in my earlier answer, but then you begin the merge on the individual hosts and send the items to the primary host that does the big merge.

Comment: You write excellent answers @JimMischel. Have you ever considered writing a book? I could see you writing something similar to the popular "Grokking Algorithms". Either way, thanks very much for this!

Comment: @duhaime Yes, I have written a few books. It's been a while, though.

Answer (score 1):

Do each of the 8000 files first need to be sorted by key or are they already sorted by key? If the 8000 first need to be sorted by key, that initial phase will be CPU bound. This initial phase to sort the files can be done in parallel (and multi-threaded, such as gnu sort). After this point, the process normally becomes file I/O bound, during the merge steps, but if the file I/O with the SSD's can be done independently, then the merge phases can also be done in parallel, using groups of SSD's. Eventually a final merge to produce a single sorted file will be file I/O bound and there would be no advantage to attempting a parallel implementation of this.

Comment: this sounds good, but I just want to check: Are you suggesting something like we have multiple rounds of merging, in which we first merge between two of the 8,000 files, then we merge between two of those merged files, and so forth, until we're left with one final merge between two files? Even then, will subdividing the keyspace and having workers seek to find and then merge their key ranges not be worthwhile?

Comment: With all due respect, @rcgldr, **are you sure of the forcast for the initial phase**, given the SSD-s are the ad-hoc instantiated node-local, whereas the cohort of files to process reside non-locally, far ( read slow + add CERN reported experience of a will to run any concurrent fileIO ) "across" the 1983 AFS file-system, not local SSD one ( so add also the central side DES-encrypt + DES-decrypt + growing pains upon any higher degree of concurrent requests ( not [PARALLEL], but "just"-[concurrent], served at best effort or WAIT ) blocking singularity of the central AFS-metadata provisioning )?

Comment: @user3666197 - I updated my answer. The "initial phase" is only done if each of the 8000 files needs to be sorted by key. If all 8000 files are already sorted by key, then there's no need for an initial sort phase.

Comment: @duhaime - It is common to limit a k-way file merge to 16 way for hard drives with a transfer rate around 100MB/S. If much more than a 16 way merge is used, what is saved in the number of merge phases may be lost due to cpu overhead. For SSDs with a transfer rate around 500MB/S (or much faster in the case of PCIe SSDs), the optimal value for k in a k-way merge may be less. In your case, you have multiple nodes and drives. If the drives can be accessed independently by the nodes, then you could perform multiple k-way merges in parallel.

Comment: @rcgldr yes, this is exactly what I'm implementing now. Thanks for confirming that this seems to be a reasonable way forward, and for these stats

Comment: @rcgldr are you sure to promise ~ 500 [MB/s] IOs for the O/P, given CERN has published to never go above ~ 60 [MB/s] on AFS with additional performance singularities ( read bottlenecks ), driven by the design limitations of the Andrew File System? Yale policy paper cites the same as ***"Accessibility,
sharing and capacity are higher priority than performance."*** This seems the promise does not match the observed facts.

Comment: @user3666197 - I wasn't aware of the external limitations of the environment, only  that many SATA SSDs are rated at about 500MB/S for sequential reads. On the extreme end, some PCIe based SSDs like [seagate nytro](https://www.seagate.com/enterprise-storage/nytro-drives/nytro-enterprise-nvme/) are rated at up to 8GB/S for sequential reads.

Answer (score 1):

This is an already solved problem.  Most mapreduce frameworks, such as Hadoop, do a distributed sort under the hood.  The best ones will come complete with logic to detect failing machines, take them out, and redo their work.  (When you're working with large distributed systems at scale, compensating for machine failure is important.)  Just find a good framework and use it, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

As for how they sort it, I understand that the standard approach is a mergesort.  At first you are handing out chunks of work that look like, "Sort this block."  Then you start handing out chunks of work that look like, "Merge these chunks together."  The tricky bit comes when your chunks to merge do not fit on a single computer.  Then you need to take a group of chunks, and figure out where to partition it, then merge the pieces.  I am not positive how they accomplish that.  My best off the cuff idea would be to take something like an every thousand'th element subselection, sort that, partition it, and tell each machine that holds the full data where to cut their datasets into chunks, and who go send data to for the merging.

However it is done, you will eventually wind up with an ordered set of machines, each of which has an ordered section of data, and between them you have the full data all sorted.

**IMPORTANT:** When dealing with large distributed data sets, it is very important to avoid creating bottlenecks anywhere.  Implicitly or explicitly.  You start with distributed data.  You process it in a distributed way.  You wind up with distributed data.  Always.

Comment: do you have specific mapreduce frameworks you'd check? I don't have sudo on either cluster, so need to work with software the cluster admins have provisioned. I wrote to them directly to ask if they're aware of turnkey solutions to this problem on their cluster, and they said they didn't know of any, but if you could list a few frameworks I'll look at the clusters more closely...

Comment: @duhaime Hadoop comes to mind.  And per http://blog.ditullio.fr/2015/12/24/hadoop-basics-filter-aggregate-sort-mapreduce/#Using_aSort_Comparator you can even choose a custom sort comparator.

Comment: @btilly Given you promote a certain "***product***" as the promising, if not the right one (assuming a distributed dataset processing would somehow justify all costs for a one-shot key:value collection & consolidation)- **are you sure** these all add-on costs will remain reasonable, given the initial state is file-based ( burried in ~8k files of ~6 TB total, fragmented over some un-guaranteed, low-perf., distributed AFS storage with both desing & policy originated perf. ceilings - **will this ecosystem ever justify to convert a trivial file-processing to Hadoop?** If not, why you recommend it?

Comment: @duhaime - back to the square No. 1, could you post details about the real-infrastructure - as provided from NUMA / `hwloc` - **`lstopo`** command line with cluster job-scheduling policies ( limits of usage ) that will be applicable to your Project ? Having seen university grants for performance comparisons of cloud operated Hadoop Map/Red v/s other raw data-processing technologies, they were only at the very end surprised, that the Hadoop was run "inside" just-virtualised resources (the performance was crippled without any chance to justify such mental error).So avoid to repeat a wrong way...

Comment: @user3666197 The first cluster uses SLURM and resources are documented here: https://research.computing.yale.edu/support/hpc/clusters/grace The second cluster uses Sun Grid Engine and resources are documented here: https://crc.nd.edu/index.php/services/policies That said, I really don't want to optimize too much for these particular clusters -- I'm more after principles that generalize to other hardware / software / network setups...

Comment: @user3666197 Compare the cost and reliability of using an existing proven software solution with the cost and reliability of having someone write a home-grown custom written piece of software for the same.  The cost of exporting data from AFS is the same whether it goes to another filesystem or a custom job, and so that cost is unimportant in your decision.  MapReduce and Hadoop are well-known enough keywords that I would hope that the people running the cluster know what to recommend for someone who thinks those are answers to their problem...

Comment: @user3666197 And moving on, my recommendation for using MapReduce is based on best practices when I was at Google.  Admittedly their infrastructure is much better than you'd expect at a university.  If things have been set up wrong, you can cripple any technology.  But store data in a distributed data store, process it in a distributed way, then store it again distributed works well.  Internal benchmarks put their general purpose MapReduce within a few percent of the best benchmarks anywhere for a custom-written distributed sort.

Comment: @btilly Agree, also have directed the O/P to contact the Yale HPC Team first. ( nice probability calculations on your blog, Sir ). Last update - ~6TB is by far not a "Google"-scale, is it? I liked a lot the Rob Pike's SAWZALL approach, almost anti-pattern, to vastly distributed, independent workloads at scale, right because of just-enough design and resulting run-time efficiency. So I prefer to tune performance of the process, than to bend a process as far as to become able to re-use some general purpose ( marketing over-hyped ) product. Thanks for your kind opinions expressed.

Comment: @user3666197 Google has lots of datasets in the multi-terabyte size range..and some a lot bigger as well.  Still it is big enough for distributed techniques to make sense.  SAWZALL is indeed a very good tool.  However I found that it has the same "exceptions for me but not for thee" mindset that also annoyed me in Go.  Some things that go wrong I really do want to hear about, guaranteed.  And no, I don't want division by 0 to be a panic...

Comment: @btilly Given we've had multi-TB sets in late 90's with TELCO data, did not expect twenty years later anything **under `{ PB, EB }`** in production and counting `:o)`

Comment: @user3666197 The big ones are very, very big.  I don't know how big they get.  Individual teams, though, often wind up dealing with much smaller data sets of things that are relevant for their project.  There are many, many data sets floating around of all sizes.  Also companies have different philosophies.  Google does "everything distributed, great architecture to scale indefinitely".  Amazon by contrast does a surprising amount of, "Let's try to reduce this to a data set that we can process in a few hours on one machine, much more cheaply than distributed allows."

Comment: @btilly Either approach makes sense. Guess Dr. Wiedermann is laughing and laughing at naive attempts to escape from TimeDOMAIN + SpaceDOMAIN complexity traps, that none of the "just"-[CONCURRENT] but even no true-[PARALLEL] computing device can principally solve - all principally fail to escape from exponentially scaled problem, intractable using our common, pure-[SEQUENTIAL] computing-process scheduling >>> http://www.quantumforquants.org/answer/re-complexity-classes-are-we-on-the-cusp-of-change/ **+add re-formulated Amdahl's Law** >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 Game Over.

Comment: @user3666197 Quantum computing doesn't change things as much as popular speculation would say.  See https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3848 for a more detailed and informed answer.  As for either approach, write things in an easy language like Python.  Now carefully optimized code on a single machine can typically gain 1-2 orders of magnitude of performance over that but with a ceiling.  Distributed **loses** an order of magnitude of performance over the naive solution, but can scale forever.  Both take more programmer time than you think.  Choose wisely...

Comment: @btilly Sorry if the post was more confusing ( the citation of Dr. Wiedermann was the merit ), it was not about QC per-se ( I know QC / QUBO scaling and other issues, not only from popularisation texts ), yet the point was about principal limits from scheduling and tools used. As per scaling, there is the dog burried. War goes on clever latency masking + keeping principal overheads justified by the [distributed-computing] resources paid indirectly by all TimeDOMAIN-costs. On paper, I sketched ~15[s] AFS in-flow + mass.-split-processing + w/c ~147[s] resulting files AFS-save. Not 30+days as-was

Comment: Cluster conditions may reduce AFS concurrent IO-flows, yet the in-flow can become almost latency-masking-wise 1:1 (almost)-zero-lag  ~1 [us] pipelined into massively concurrent pool of distributed-sorting nodes (unknown distribution of loads-no adaptivity), yet with an immense positive effect on overall performance ( completely an anti-pattern to the posted / accepted hierarchy of moving interim pre-sorted stages upwards the 16:4:1 concentration of data-flow + reduction of performance ). I like the latency-masking flow-based smart data-hydraulics view on how to approach the HPC solutions :o)

Comment: I wrote a recursive k-way merge as seems to be the consensus and Yale's cluster will be done with it before the day is through. That said, I'd like to see your notes, user3666197. btilly, is it true that Hadoop sorts keys before passing them to the reduce function? If so, could I just stream each of the 8000 input files in the map step and combine each key's values in the reduce step linearly? This seems too easy...

Comment: @duhaime That is exactly how you do it. :-)

Comment: Here is why they do that.  Before you reduce, you have to somehow gather keys together.  The two natural ways of doing that are to pass it through a sort or a hash.  Hashing has the win of being `O(n)` instead of `O(n log(n))`.  But it has the severe drawback that you can easily overload a node that accidentally gets several "hot keys" assigned to it.  It is a pure bonus that sorting presents values in sorted order, and makes it more likely that further processing can benefit from locality of reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your compare method is not very complicated, the bottleneck is most-likely the file-IO. This will get worse when you do it over a network rather than on a local hard drive. (But you can only be sure after profiling)

I'm sure the file-IO is your bottleneck  (But you can only be sure after profiling).

I would recommend:

1. Load the data in big chunks into RAM (as big as you can) use quicksort on each chunk to sort it in RAM and write it as one file per chunk to disc.
2. Use your k-way merge to merge this big sorted files.

Comment: With all due respect, Sir, this does not answer the core issue - How to design such process inside a distributed-computing environment smart and efficiently. If you remain consistent with your a-priori belief the main bottlenect is disk-I/O, then the per-partes organised sorting is not a way to go way faster in TimeDOMAIN, given the available range of ~ 10.000 x 120 GB RAM SpaceDOMAIN-equipped nodes with 12-24 CPU-cores.

Comment: @user3666197: My main point is: Before distributing a problem, first analyze if that really addresses the bottleneck of your problem. If IO is the problem, you will get no benefit by distributing the algorithm if IO remains bad or gets even worse (by using a shared file system accessed via network instead of files on a local disc). So first step profile what your bottleneck is.

Comment: In a single-host sort/merge, I/O a big factor, but not the limiting factor. The time is split fairly evenly among I/O, doing the initial file sorts, and the final merge. Having multiple hosts gives you a linear increase on the initial file sorts and on at least half of the I/O. The final merge and output, done on a single host, still takes significant time, but the first half of the problem goes *much* faster.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: *'I/O a big factor, but not the limiting factor'*. What else could be the limiting factor? Merge Sort does nothing but **read**, compare and **write** the compare should take no time in compare to the read and write from/to the filesystem. Sorting big chunks in RAM avoids loads of reads and writes to the file-system. After reducing the file I/O this way you can still consider distribution between hosts, if speed is still too slow.

Comment: I/O is an O(n) operation. Sorting is an O(n log n) operation. So the time to sort increases faster than the time required to write. There comes a point, especially when comparisons are expensive, that sorting time is larger than I/O time.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: MergeSort does not read / write the data only once when you cannot hold all of it in RAM. So you will need to read/wirte the data from disc O(log n) times. That makes the number of I/O also O(n log n) and if comparing is not very complicated the constant is most likely worse for the i/o than for the compare-function.

Comment: Assuming you have enough memory to hold even a small buffer for each of the sorted sub-files, every item is read twice from disk and written twice to disk. The number of I/O operations is linear with n. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort